# Использование "сегодняшний" и "сегодня"

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные, разговорная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **как** грамотно:
***Сегодняшним утром*** в парке я встретил знакомого.

Или:
***Сегодня утром*** в парке я встретил знакомого.

Вообще, в чем различие между ***сегодняшним утром*** и ***сегодня утром***?
Наверное, первый вариант — разговорный? Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С грамотностью здесь всё в порядке, но второй вариант естественнее.
Первое выражение *по стилю* больше подходит для речи с трибуны: оно громоздко для повседневной речи, но может послужить для привлечения внимания.

Вспоминается реплика профессора Хиггинса из "Пигмалиона" по поводу *важнической* манеры речи мусорщика: "У этого человека врождённый дар риторики".
В разговорной же речи можно и очевидное "сегодня" пропустить.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Уж слишком громко звучит прилагательное ''сегодняшний' в этом примере. Достаточно ''сегодня'' или просто, как отметил Александр, ''утром''.  разговорной речи, где это возможно, лучше заменить ''сегодняшний'' на ''сегодня''.

Comment: Alex_ander, Серж, спасибо вам за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, прилагательное СЕГОДНЯШНИЙ закрепилось в разговорном стиле, но теперь вошло и в письменную речь, правда, скорее в деловой речи: на сегодняшний день (как на текущий момент), но употребляется и в публицистическом: жить сегодняшним днём.

Ваше предложение ведь в разговорном стиле, почему возник вопрос? Слово здесь на месте, но можно сказать и сегодня утром, как Вам нравится, всё корректно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, очень много примеров, когда жаргонные слова проникли и ужились в литературе, став (как в данном примере) также литературной формой, а порой и вовсе вытеснив её (как, например, слово "доярка", которая была ничуть не лучше "училки", "медички"). И в этом отношении предложение "Сегодняшним утром в парке я встретил знакомого" является допустимым по нормам современного русского языка, увы и ах, но (к счастью!) никак ни грамотным. А потому, рассматривая вопрос с аспекта грамотности построения речи, мы должны признать, что её каноны бесспорно требуют употребить второй вариант, так как первый вариант ("сегодняшним утром"), как филологи, так и литераторы посчитают определённо "режущим слух". Иными словами грамотной формой всё ещё остаётся "Сегодня утром..."

P.S. Позвольте добавить, что **пока ещё** стандарты грамотной речи также требуют составить Ваше предложение в несколько иной форме - никто не сможет Вам **"подсказать"**, ибо подсказать можно только то, что Вы забыли, а не знали. А потому Вам бы следовало написать не **"Подскажите, пожалуйста, вариант"**, а **"Скажите, пожалуйста..."**

ИМХО!

Comment: **"Откуда дровишки? Ваши знакомые филологи так говорят?"**
==============================
Уважаемый "Niemand", а Вам уже не режет слух **"Сегодняшним утром в парке встретить знакомого?"** Если нет, то поверьте уж, что это печально.

P.S. Мне пришлось здесь отвечать Вам, так как по какой-то непонятной мне причине в Вашем комментарии нет ни "комментировать", ни "ответить".

**Буду благодарен всем, кто прояснит мне эту странную ситуацию**